# how to compare two dates in if condation in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, date, controller, php-carbon

in my controller i used Carbon to get current timestamp like showing below:

```
$current_timestamp = Carbon::now()->format('j/n/Y');
```

the output of the above:

```
18/8/2022
```

and i am getting data from external API like showing below (from blade):

```
$data[0]['DocDate']
```

the output of the above:

```
18/8/2022 12:00:00 AM
```

now i want to remove `12:00:00 AM` from it

i tried in blade view to do:

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($data[29]['DocDate'])->toDateString()}}
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Could not parse '18/8/2022 12:00:00 AM': Failed to parse time string (18/8/2022 12:00:00 AM) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
```

and i tried:

```
$data[29]['DocDate']->format('j/n/Y')
```

and i get this error:

```
Call to a member function format() on string
```

how can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use create from format function to change the format of incoming date as below:

```
$inDate = $data[0]['DocDate'];

$outDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s a', $inDate )->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

On the principle of Keep It Simple - Why not just compare them as strings?, the longer one can easily be shortened, then just compare.
Accepted this is not a "purest" approach, but the format of a "standard" date is not likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

> now i want to remove 12:00:00 AM from it

So you don't actually care about date, you don't need Carbon or parsing according to format, you just need to keep the first word of your string:

```
{{ explode(' ', $data[0]['DocDate'])[0] }}
```